# Charting Library for use with Quantlib C++

Tags: charts, quantlib

I've recently built Quantlib and am trying now to find a decent charting library for use with Quantlib.  Has anyone used Quantlib and what did you use for charts?

Has to be in C++.  Dynamically or Statically linked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be can have take a loot at [ChartDirector](http://www.advsofteng.com), which has a C++ edition.

Comment: Hmm. thanks but I was hoping for a free library ;) .. I was just wondering what everyone uses.